# FFmpeg: how to burn subtitles into only part of the video?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encode, subtitle

I have a video which lasts for an hour but the ass subtitle only has the first 30 seconds. I want to burn this 30 seconds subtitle file into this video. Here are two options I have tried:

- `ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf "ass=a.ass" -ss 00:00:00 -t 30 b.mp4` 
  Then I only get a 30-second long video.
- `ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -vf "ass=a.ass"  b.mp4` I can get the whole one-hour long video but it takes a long time!

How can I only encode only the first 30 seconds of this video and keep the rest of it unchanged (like the copy option) so that it takes less time to finish this burning process?

Comment: Why not just use the ASS softsubs instead of burning?

Comment: Ass softsubs cannot be shown when streaming online.

Comment: Use VTT subs if you're using HTML5.

Comment: If shaping- simple is not an option for you or not fast enough (http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ass), and you really, really need more speed then you might want to experiment with transcoding 2 separate videos: a 10 seconds one and a 59:50 one, then concat them. Hope ffmpeg can seek frame-accurate in your video. If not, rewrapping might help